# Nginx rewrite, split path every n characters?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a quite a few photos available on an nginx server, and to future proof it I decided to nest them into folders.  The structure is simple, each image has a 6 or more digit id, so I decided I'd split that id every 3 characters making each section a folder, and putting all the images specific to that id in the last folder.

This works fine, but I wanted to make accessing the images easier, and it crossed my mind it may be possible to craft a rewrite rule that would take in just the id (/1234567/9.jpg for example) and rewrite it to the correct path (/123/456/7/9.jpg).
Is this possible with nginx's rewrite capabilities?

Comment: is there a limit to the depth of the folders?

Comment: @Mohammad, the ids are between 4 and 8 characters long, so it could be 2 or 3 folders.